# Do you can bind a python server socket to an public ip?

Tags: python, sockets

so my problem is I trying to bind the socket to my public ip but I always get the error 'This ip is not right in that context'.So how I could fix that or is it not possible to bind the socket server to an public ip?

Comment: If that' the literal error text the Python people need to be excoriated (for changing the existing text of the error message), but you can't bind any socket to a non-local IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a socket only to a local IP that belongs to the device that is running your code. If an IP belongs to an external device, for instance a LAN router, then you cannot bind to it.  In that situation, you would have to instead bind to a local LAN IP/port on the network interface that is connected to the router, and then configure the router to port-forward inbound traffic from the public WAN IP/port to the server's bound LAN IP/port.